# Get numbers from string RegExp

Tags: jquery, regex

I have string like that

```
(111|222) N999
```

And i want to get

```
x = 111
y = 222
```

with RegExp but i don't know how to do it.
Can anyone help me with that

i've play around on https://regex101.com but i was able only to get first 3 numbers with \d+. I could't get values after |

Comment: The idea is: use regex to get (111|222), then split the result based `|`.

Comment: Well then this isnt the right place to ask this is it?

Comment: Yes @Rishav bad question with no no attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one rush:

```js
let data = '(111|222) N999 ';
var rx = /\(([^|]+)\|([^)]+)\)/g;
match = rx.exec(data);
if (match) {
    x = match[1];
    y = match[2];
    console.log("x:", x, "y:", y);
}
```

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BfX7Mo/1).

Answer (score 0):

For your given example, as an alternative you could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `()|`:

```js
var splitted = "(111|222) N999".split(/[()|]/);
console.log("x: ", splitted[1]);
console.log("y: ", splitted[2]);
```